# How do I implement the use of anonymous health checks while using the Microsoft identity authentication scheme?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, health-check, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm trying to implement a standard health check in `Program.cs` for a Blazor application (.NET Core 7). I'd like implement a health check to live at the endpoint `/_health` and for it to be accessile anonymously, so that my automated service can ping it routinely to asses downtime. However, I believe due to our usage of the `OpenId` authentication scheme we are unable to access this endpoint even when including the `AllowAnonymous()` extension method, as the program will by default redirect to our identity provider, evenwith `AllowAnonymous()` set on the setting `MapHealthChecks`. I believe there must be a way to still allow an anonymous access to this health check, but am unsure of how to do so. What's the best way? Program.cs:

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
        options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
        {
            context.ProtocolMessage.MaxAge = "0";
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
        options.Events.OnRemoteSignOut = context =>
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
    options.AddPolicy("ApplicationAuthorizedPolicy", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new ApplicationAuthorizationRequirement()));
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();

builder.Services.AddLocalization();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, ApplicationAuthorizationHandler>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, ClientDataAuthorizationHandler>();

// Add Health Checks
builder.Services.AddHealthChecks();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRequestLocalization("en-US");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.MapHealthChecks("/_health");
app.Run();
```

Comment: Have you tried placing `app.MapHealthChecks(...).AllowAnonymous()` before `app.MapControllers()`? Alternatively you can place them before Auth calls.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. It seems like regardless of where the health check mapping occurs, the redirect to the identity provider always occurs anyways.